# Replace value of arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Hi i looking to write a script that will update my stock figure i get from a supplier i get this file from them and the stock qty comes down at "H" high stock "N" no stock "C" low

```
// Get the pricelist into an array.
$lines = file($filename);
// Loop through our array
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    echo "Line #<b>{$line_num}</b> : " . htmlspecialchars($line) . "<br /><BR>\n";

    $column = explode ( '"~"', $line ); // use the "~" as explode char
    echo $column[0] . " sku <BR>";
    echo $column[13] . " stock <BR>";
    echo $column[15] . " ean/upc <BR>";
```

This is what i got so far but this replace has got me pulling hair out i have tried a few things but with no luck i know it will be something silly and easy to some you guy i thank you in advance.

Regards
Stuart

Comment: which colume contains these values `"H" high stock "N" no stock "C" low` . What is the column structure in your file?

Comment: /pricelist.php?action=pricelist&&stock=on&ean=on&plaintext=on

i have changed it as don't need as many fields from document now but
sku[0]
stock[1]1
ean/upc[2]

Answer (score 0):

```
$stock=array("H"=> "high stock", "N"=> "no stock", "C"=> "low");
```

create an array to easily match the short code to the text you want to use

```
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    echo "Line #<b>{$line_num}</b> : " . htmlspecialchars($line) . "<br /><BR>\n";

    $column = explode ( '"~"', $line ); // use the "~" as explode char
    echo $column[0] . " sku <BR>";
    echo $stock[$column[13]] . " stock <BR>"; //match short code to full text
    echo $column[15] . " ean/upc <BR>";
```

Comment: Sorry to be a pain been too long time since i have used this but when trying to run next part of script i get error i have tried the below :

   // Connect to Database
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','pass','dynamo')
 or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

// update data in mysql database 
$sql="UPDATE oc_products SET sku='".$column[0] ."', Number='".$stock[$column[1]]."' WHERE '".$column[0]"' = '".$column[0]."'";

&

$sql = "UPDATE `oc_products` ( `sku` , `quantity`) VALUES ('".$column[0]."' , '".$stock[$column[1]]."')";

Thanks

Comment: you should really post that as a new question